# GWT - DevMode: 'gwt.google.com not found' - 'Cannot display web page'

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gwt-dev-mode

really need some help.

I have been working for the past 3 days trying to get a webpage to open when I run my web based Java-GWT-eclipse program. IE gives me error "Internet Explorer cannot display webpage" and chrome says "The webpage is not available- The server at gwt.google.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed."

I have tried this project on multiple other computers with an older eclipse-gwt plugin installed and it works great. All of these computers are dev boxes and do not have internet access. It does, however, have a solid connection to the database (SQL dev works fine).

what i have tried

1. copied eclipse and gwt plugin files from another dev box and installed. Gave me above error.
2. deleted/ uninstalled everything and installed newest version eclipse and gwt plugin. I was able to install gwt in eclipse but it could not locate GWT-user.jar file and would not allow me to create project.
3. Tried #2 again, same problem. Tried again on another computer, same problem.
4. Applied older version SDK to newer eclipse version. Gave same error as posted above/ #1.
5. ran wireshark on a working dev and the problem dev and the problem dev box was trying to communicate with google while the good one was going to some local IP address.
6. messed around with every setting in eclipse and nothing has worked.

What is left to try??? I am going insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the web page you are trying to open: `http://gwt.google.com` ?

Does this page load if you write the url directly in the address box of your browser ?

Does Internet work in that computer? try to access google or any other page.

This error is a clear case of a miss-configuration on your PC internet stack:

`The server at gwt.google.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.`

What does return this command in your console?

```
nslookup gwt.google.com
```

EDITED:

After reading your comments I figure out what is happening: your browser has not the gwt-plugin installed, so the first time it connects to a gwt-dev-mode app, the app redirects it to the gwt site to download the plugin and install it.

You have either, connect this computer to the internet to install the plugin the first time it is requested, or download the plugin and install it manually.

Comment: No when I run eclipse it generates a local web address that i double click on (ex: 127.0.0.1:8888 etc.). The computer is a dev box that is not allowed to have an internet connection, it can only connect to the server. The problem is that eclipse shouldn't need to contact Google, it should run independently.

Comment: the nslookup returns" Unknown can't find gwt.google.com: No response from server" but I would expect this as there is no internet connection.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you!! Basically I did not get redirected to the plugin because my computer did not have internet access. Getting a plugin to work on an offline computer was a whole new issue, but eventually found a way with ie9.